# EKS: Usable Memory goes lower and lower on the node to 5% then jumps up to 80% available

Tags: kubernetes, eks

I was able to correlate the "usable memory" going down with events in kubernetes:

```
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Tue, 06 Jun 2023 19:31:34 +0000   Thu, 11 May 2023 15:24:32 +0000   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
```

The time of the `LastTransitionTime` coincides with the lowest memory and the transition to a lot of available memory.

Also, I think that during the times of low available memory I get a lot of OOM errors and processes are getting killed with exit code 137.

Is there something misconfigured in this Kubernetes cluster? I think the available memory should not ever go that low and it should start evicting pods earlier. Also I don't understand why the whole memory becomes available - this means that we are evicting ALL pods?

[image: memory available goes lower and lower then jumps up]

Answer (score 0):

From the get-go, my educated guess would be memory leak your workloads. It seems that his happens pretty regular - every 12 hours, do you have some scheduled/cron job?

Alternative problem could be overcommitted resources.

First of all check `resources.limits` on workloads you are running on the EKS cluster. Make sure `resources.limits.memory` is set on every single container. You can play around with [limit ranges](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/limit-range/) to set defaults for a namespace; this way you "protect" your nodes to some extent (alternative is to use [resource quotas](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/).

I see you are using Datadog, you can leverage Kubernetes metrics to find spiking workload - `kubernetes.memory.working_set` ([reference](https://docs.datadoghq.com/containers/kubernetes/data_collected/)):

> Current working set in bytes - this is what the OOM killer is watching for

The description of metric you are currently using ([reference](https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/guide/calculating-the-system-mem-used-metric/)):

> The `system.mem.usable` metric represents free memory plus cached memory plus buffers (on Linux, it reflects “MemAvailable” attribute from `/proc/meminfo` whenever possible).

On a "cluster" side of things you may enable ["resource reservation"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/), which may help with keeping system daemons (like `kubelet`) alive. Also read docs on node [pressure evictions and thresholds](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/#hard-eviction-thresholds).